# Sharepoint OnPremise Integration with Azure

Tags: python, azure, sharepoint, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

Is there any way to integrate SharePoint on premise with Azure ADF,though there is a SharePoint connector in azure ADF but its only work with SharePoint online.

Is there any other way around to download from SharePoint on premise using python or scala

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just for now, Data Factory doesn't support on-premise SharePoint as the connector.

About your another question, we can't tell you there is or not, you must test it by yourself. One of the workarounds is that use the Azure databricks python notebook, I searched fount these documents may helpful: [Connect your Azure Databricks workspace to your on-premises
network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/on-prem-network)

There isn't an exist tutorial/example for you. The last thing is that you need to build/design the code logic/library to connect to your on-premise sharepoint.